# slow UPDATE of rows by COUNTing from another table

Tags: mysql, query-performance, update, mariadb-10.4

I try to update a table by counting rows from another table as

```
UPDATE t1 SET c1 = (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t2 WHERE t2.id=t1.id GROUP BY id
    )
```

strangely, this query stuck at `Sending data` state for hours.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t2
```

returns ~16M in 2 seconds.

```
SELECT id FROM t2 GROUP BY id
```

returns 50K rows in 5 seconds.

The table structures are very simple

```
CREATE TABLE t2
(
item int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
id mediumint(7) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (item,id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: How long did the accepted answer take?

Comment: @Vérace 12 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove correlation:

```
UPDATE t1 
JOIN ( SELECT t2.id, COUNT(*) c1 
       FROM t2
       GROUP BY t2.id ) t3 ON t3.id=t1.id
SET t1.c1 = t3.c1;
```

Answer (score 1):

`t2` has no useful index.  It needs `INDEX(id)` for much-improved speed.

If you have watered down the table and queries, then this answer may not be sufficient.